# Parse Facebook Login App Must Ask For Basic Read Permission

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, parse-platform

I am building a Parse driven iOS application and am having some strange issues with Facebook login. Upon initializing my facebook permissions, I am asking for @"email" and nothing else. The login works when the user does not have the facebook iOS application installed on their device - and authenticates through safari (or another web browser). When the user DOES have the facebook iOS application installed and tries to grant permission to my app, the following error is displayed:

[image: facebook login bug ("the app must ask for a basic read permission at install time")]

I have read through multiple tutorials and related stack overflow issues, and have yet to figure this one out. I tested this out with both an older version of the facebook SDK and the brand new one (3.5). Neither of those solutions appears to work. Anyone have any ideas? Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with both @"email" and @"basic_info". This is currently documented on the Android side, but not iOS, which is weird - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/native-login/

Comment: @MingLi: I would really appreciate your guidance with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276666/send-a-message-to-a-facebook-friend-from-an-android-app).